# Does Location matter while using cloud Firestore?

Tags: ios, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In a hurry I put a wrong location in my cloud Firestore setup. I am not allowed to change it. Currently I'm staying in Singapore but the location I have put is US. Can someone help me what should I do? What will happen if I continue with that location for my database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce latency you should take a location near you or more precise your users. Unfortunately you can't change the location of a firestore database once selected. What you can do is to create a new one and set the location of that one near you and your users. Just don't forget to replicate that in you firebase configuration in your app.

Comment: Thanks got it. Have changed it to a location near me